# How can you pass a pretrainend LDA Model to ldaseq in Gensim for DTM?

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have a tuned and pretrainend LDA Model that I want to pass on to the ldaseq model in gensim, but don't understand how to do it. I've tried lda_model and sstats but it doesn'T seem to work, I still get this from the logging:

> running online (multi-pass) LDA training, 10 topics, 10 passes over
> the supplied corpus of 1699 documents, updating model once every 1699
> documents, evaluating perplexity every 1699 documents, iterating 50x
> with a convergence threshold of 0.001000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever wonders this:
initialize='own' you need to supply sstats of the previously trained model in the shape (vocab_len, num_topics), and initialize='lda_model' you need to supply the previously trained lda model.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/NLPatVCU/Sentiment-Classification/blob/master/keras_test/keras_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.py)